# Weird spacing in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, whitespace, space

Please have a look at the image given below and guide me how to fix it. This is making difficult it to read the comments and it is annoying because I like to have my code perfectly indented. Please help me out.

In the image tabsize is 8 (I set it for demonstration purpose)

[image: ir]

Comment: How can it be perfectly indented with an 8-space tab??!1!? Perfect implies two spaces! Joking aside: something is very off with either your font, your character spacings, or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably caused by using a non-monospace font. To fix, try to reset your font the default settings:

1. Type `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the command menu
2. Type `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`
3. Remove the line starting with `"editor.fontFamily"`

Comment: Definitely something up with the font: the `#` is also messed up.